# create std::vector from function application

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl, stdvector

Given a vector `v1` of objects, and a function operating on them, returning a value,

```
std::vector<OBJ> v1; // already filled
bool foo(const OBJ&);
```

what would be the cleanest way to create a `vector<bool> v2`, coming from application of `foo` to each element of `v1`? I would prefer to not write a loop but I can't find a suitable command in the STL.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `std::transform`.

Of course there is a loop, but it's an implementation detail of `transform`.

example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename Obj, typename IsTrue>
std::vector<bool> truth(std::vector<Obj> const& v, IsTrue&& truth_func)
{
    auto result = std::vector<bool>(v.size());
    std::transform(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 
                   std::begin(result), 
                   std::forward<IsTrue>(truth_func));
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    auto is_even = [](auto&& x)
    {
        return (x % 2) == 0;
    };

    auto vb = truth(v, is_even);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So it's probably faster to set the vector size instead of using a back_inserter?

Comment: @rwst Using `back_inserter` relies on the vector expanding itself (and possibly copying all of its data) whenever it reaches capacity. For a huge vector, the amortized cost of that is constant and very low, because vectors expand geometrically, but it's still not zero. But if you're doing this a zillion times with very small vectors, rather than once with a huge vector, there's no time to amortize over—you could be adding a 4-element copy to a 5-element operation every time, and nearly doubling the cost.

Comment: More unrelated: can this be executed in parallel, maybe with C++17 somehow? I mean the objects are read-only so in principle this should work?

Comment: @rwst it's in the standard, yes. Not all stdlib implementation support parallel ops yet. your mileage may vary. See overload 4: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with solution using `std::transform`. However, we could do it with much simpler `std::for_each()` from `<algorithm>`.

We consider each elements of vector `vec` (which is your `OBJ`), `insert` the `bool` return from `foo()` at the back/ end of the next vector `v`.

Something like as follows. Here is the live action: https://www.ideone.com/pyfqmF

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using OBJ = int;

bool foo(const OBJ& a)
{ return a == 1; }

int main()
{
   std::vector< OBJ > vec = {1, 2, 3, 4};
   std::vector< bool > v;
   v.reserve(vec.size());

   std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&v](const OBJ& a)->void
      {
         v.insert(v.end(), foo(a) );
      });

   for(auto const& it: v) std::cout << it << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```